# How to find the average value from a list of tuples that share the same key?

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples, user-input

I have two lists created from user inputs that I combined into a list of tuples with the following code:

```
daily_hours_list = [4, 2, 1, None, 3, 5]
week_counter_list = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]

weekly_hours_list = []
for week, time in zip(week_counter_list, daily_hours_list):
    if time != None:
        weekly_hours_list.append((week, t))
```

Which gives me:

```
weekly_hours_list = [(1, 4),
                     (1, 2),
                     (1, 1),
                     (2, 3),
                     (2, 5)]
```

I then used this code to sum all hours in week 1 and all hours in week 2:

```
tup_h = {i:0 for i, v in weekly_hours_list}
for key, value in weekly_hours_list:
    tup_h[key] = tup_h[key]+value
weekly_sum_hours = list(map(tuple, tup_h.items()))
```

Giving me:

```
weekly_sum_hours = [(1, 6),
                    (2, 8)]
```

This all works fine but how do I find the average hours for each week like:

```
weekly_average_list = [(1, 2),
                       (2, 4)]
```

I imagine I would need to expand on the for loop calculation, accounting for the count of tuples with week values of 1 and 2, but not sure how to implement that. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I think would be helpful would be to first collect together the hours for each week. This could be easily done with a dictionary where the key is the week number, and the value is a list of hours for that week. There's a data structure called a `defaultdict` in the built-in `collections` module that is designed exactly for a situtation like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from statistics import mean

daily_hours_list = [4, 2, 1, None, 3, 5]
week_counter_list = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]

daily_hours_by_week = defaultdict(list)
for week, time in zip(week_counter_list, daily_hours_list):
    if time is not None:
        daily_hours_by_week[week].append(time)

sum_hours_by_week = {w: sum(hours) for w, hours in daily_hours_by_week.items()}
avg_hours_by_week = {w: mean(hours) for w, hours in daily_hours_by_week.items()}
```

In our example, this means you don't have to initialize the dictionary with an empty list for each week number (which is what you did with your initial sum of `0` for `tup_h`). Instead, if we ever try to append an hour to a week which isn't yet in the dictionary, it will create an empty list to put under that key and then append to that.

Once we've got our hours organised per-week like this, it's really easy to do other processing on them.

We could actually do the last two lines at once and create a single dictionary with a statistics-per-week tuple:

```
statistics_by_week = {w: sum(hours), mean(hours) for w, hours in daily_hours_by_week.items()}
```

Read more details on `defaultdict` here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome!  Btw, I thought it was really neat how you set up `tup_h` with an initial sum of `0` so you could just go ahead and add straight into it. When I referred to it in my answer, it was meant to be an encouragement of "you're already thinking along these lines" rather than "why aren't you using the right data structure". You'd pretty much got the key insight for solving the problem neatly, you just didn't know about the data structure that would do the heavy lifting for you. Very happy to introduce it to you - `defaultdict` is a really useful thing to know.